# Change 'edit' Button Color from moreNavigationController of UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to change 'edit' Button Color from moreNavigationController of UITabBarController?
How can i do it ??

I tried to search for how can i do it about 3-4 hour but I can't got any proper solution.

I write following code of line but it nor work for me.

```
self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.editButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Please Give any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find The Solution by using **Delegate** method of `UINavigationController`.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UINavigationController Delegate Methods

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController  willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController  animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    UINavigationBar *morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;
    morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; // Set Color as you need. 
}
```

Its Work for me :)